# Node.js Express unhandledRejection removeListener

Tags: node.js, express

I have some error handling in my Express app, for async/await functionality, ie. trying to handle the uncaught errors centrally, to respond with appropriate status codes/messages.

I'm doing like so:

```
const handleRejection = (res, reason) => {
    const { code, message } = reason
    console.trace()
    logger.error(reason)
    // use `res` to send response to client
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', handleRejection.bind(this, res))
    next()
})

process.on('SIGTERM', () => process.removeListener('unhandledRejection', handleRejection))
```

This works fine for catching/handling errors, however, my logs are filled up each time an error is triggered. I don't believe this event listener, `process.on('unhandledRejection')`, is being removed correctly at all...

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're attaching a new event handler on every request.

Then, on SIGTERM you try to remove an event handler `handleRejection` which was never attached - you didn't attach `handleRejection` but `handleRejection.bind(this, res)` which returns a different function.

It looks like you may also be leaking memory by binding the function to every `res` object for every request.

This is a very strange way to handle errors. I'm not even sure that this is indeed what you are trying to do. Do you want to add so many event hendlers (one for every request made to your server) and then remove all of them on SIGTERM, when you try to exit your server?

Comment: Oh of course :( forgot that app.use gets hit on every request. Dang. Any other way you can think of accessing the `res` object within this handler?

Comment: Basically, I'm using async/await throughout my route handlers, and I throw Errors for various scenarios (validation, DB errors, etc) and I wanted a central place to handle returning an error to the client.

Comment: So I let the `throw new Error` bubble up from the Promise (async/await) to this global handler

Comment: @benhowdle89 Maybe it would be easier to add `.catch(error => handleRejection(res, error));` to the end of your promise chain somewhere where you have the `res` object in scope. I'm not sure how you can centralize it any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for an Express middleware to pass unhandledRejection to main error middleware

```
    // Handle unhandledRejection and pass error to next middleware
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        function unhandledRejection(reason, p) {
            console.error('Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, " reason: ", reason);

            next(reason);
        }

        process.on('unhandledRejection', unhandledRejection);

        // Manage to get information from the response too, just like Connect.logger does:
        var end = res.end;
        res.end = function (chunk, encoding) {

            // Prevent MaxListener on process.events
            process.removeListener('unhandledRejection', unhandledRejection);
            res.end = end;
            res.end(chunk, encoding);
        };
        next();
    });
```